# Self-pushing object constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

So JavaScript is a functional language, classes are defined from functions and the function scope corresponds to the class constructor. I get it all now, after a rather long time studying how to OOP in JavaScript.

What I want to do is not necessarily possible, so I first want to know if this is a good idea or not. So let's say I have an array and a class like the following:

```js
var Entry = function(name, numbers, address) {
  this.name = name;
  if(typeof numbers == "string") {
    this.numbers = [];
    this.numbers.push(numbers);
  }
  else this.numbers = numbers;
  this.address = address;
};

var AddressBook = [];
```

And I add contacts with the following function:

```js
function addContact(name, numbers, address) {
  AddressBook.push(new Entry(name, numbers, address));
}
```

Can't I make it so `new Entry()` would put **itself** into `AddressBook`? If I can't do this on create, it would be interesting to do it with a method in the `Entry` prototype as well. I couldn't figure out a way to do anything similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try passing the `AddressBook` array reference to the function like such:

```
var Entry = function(name, numbers, address, addressBook) {
  this.name = name;
  if(!(numbers instanceof Array)) {
    this.numbers = [numbers];
  }
  else this.numbers = numbers;
  this.address = address;
  addressBook.push(this);
};

var addressBook = [];

function addContact(name, numbers, address) {
  new Entry(name, numbers, address, addressBook)
}
```

Comment: Great solution; is stating `new Entry` with no assigned variable standard code (i.e. does it work under strict mode)?

Comment: Simple pass-by-reference. You have the `AddressBook` array already defined in some outer scope, pass it to the new Entry (i.e. `ab` param) then after you finish setting stuff in the "constructor", you add yourself to the array that was passed in (again, it's passed by reference).

Comment: It would be strict-mode compliant if you were to do this inside the body of a function/class. As is right now AddressBook is a global, which is a no-no.

Comment: Sorry, removed the earlier comment (for others that look here, I'd asked how the solution worked).

Comment: You mean something like AddressBook being an object literal, `list: new Array(), addContact: function(name, numbers, address) { ... }` its properties?

Answer (score 3):

Reconsider the design approach.  The "Entry" object's primary role is **Information Holder**.  You should encapsulate the AddToAddressBook functionality in some sort of a controller or eventHandler.

**Details**
You've got more than 1 responsibility and it's generally not a good idea to tightly couple the 2 concerns. (e.g. Design principles involved Single Responsibility Principle and Separation of Concerns.)

**Information holder** – an object designed to know certain information and provide that information to other objects.

**Structurer** – an object that maintains relationships between objects and information about those relationships.

I'd suggest reading up on SOLID principles and try to keep each object's responsibilities narrowly focused.  Your code will be less complex and easier to maintain and extend going forward.

Check out - http://aspiringcraftsman.com/series/solid-javascript/
There's a example of products and cart which is pretty close to your scenario above.

Comment: +1 for the excellent tutorial. @rdodev answered my question and solved my problem, but yours has good advice for me and whoever runs into this question in the future